# Creating a library of functions to mutate arbitrary global variables

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Update: If I have a few functions that I want to mutate a global variable that is passed as a function argument, some can do this by passing just the symbol of the global (as in the case of pushing something onto part of a list), but other functions will require that the symbol be quoted when it is passed so I can access the symbol-value and mutate the outside variable, required for using setq in a function. This question is basically about creating a consistent interface for a user of these functions without confusing them that sometimes you pass the symbol, othertimes you pass the quoted symbol

Example way to streamline the interface for a bunch of functions, by using a helper that has the same usage reqardless of how the mutating function works:

Here are 2 basic examples of my technique:

```
(defun push-something (global something)
  (push something global)
  global) ;; not necessary to return it here since the 
          ;; preceding line already does, but doing so 
          ;; for consistency with other functions and clarity

(defun push-cdr (global something)
  (push something (cdr global))
  global) ;; must return it if I am going to set the 
          ;; dynamic var to the result of this function, 
          ;; because the preceding line doesn't return the 
          ;; entire new result of the variable

;;; "dirty" function for mutating global variable using "clean" functions above:

(defun set-global (fn global &rest values)
  (setf (symbol-value global) (apply fn (copy-list (eval global)) values)))
```

In this last one, I must `eval` the `global` since it is quoted for use with `symbol-value` and then I `copy-list` so that `global` isn't directly mutated accidentally by whatever `fn` I choose (as would be the case with `push-cdr` which might be non-trivial in more complicated functions).

Output:

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *g2* nil)
*G2*
CL-USER> (set-global #'push-something '*g2* 5)
(5)
CL-USER> *g2*
(5)
CL-USER> (set-global #'push-cdr '*g2* 99)
(5 99)
CL-USER> *g2*
(5 99)
```

...and the same functions could be used with `*g1*` or `*g3*` etc all through the access function `set-global`.

Is this good or bad style, or am I missing a much better way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: upvoted as is a real question. Thoroughly agree with sds' answer though.

Comment: This has nothing to do with 'purely functional' programming. This is  bad style, a waste of time and solves no problem.

Comment: @OpenLearner I think you've gone off on a bad track with making setters that specifically target globals instead of tapping in to CL's concept of a place. Paul Graham's "On Lisp" (pdf available free on his site) has a decent tutorial on some of the relevant techniques in Ch 12, including a "_f" macro that is similar to your set-global but works on arbitrary places. (To fit ANSI CL _f's lambda list needs "&environment env" added, and get-setf-method is replaced by get-setf-expansion, which takes the env as its last argument.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why don't you get rid of `set-global` function entirely, and if you want all your function to have the same style of passing in the global variable, just make them all use `symbol-value` so anyone using these functions won't need to know which do and which do not require a quote in front of the global variable name getting passed. Much easier right?

Answer (score 6):

This is a bad style and a waste of your time.

1. `push-something` is equivalent to `cons`.
2. `push-cdr` is *not* functional: it modifies the argument in-place or fails with an error on `nil` argument.

If you want to change the value of the global variable, then using `setf` explicitly is much clearer.

If you want to modify the internals of a global value in some intricate way, you may need to write a special function for that - but that function should be agnostic of the fact that it is modifying the value bound to a global variable as opposed to a lexical variable.

In short, there are two separate orthogonal issues - changing a global variable (use `setq`) and changing internals of an object (be agnostic of its global nature).

PS. I am not sure what you mean by "setf does not change the value of a global variable when it's inside the function", but:

```
(defvar *foo* 10)
*FOO* ==> 10
(defun change-foo (x) (setq *foo* x))
(change-foo 123)
*foo* ==> 123
```

Comment: The issue is not that these are trivial examples, but rather the idea of the best way to mutate outside objects; setf inside the function would not mutate them alone, since the scope would not be visible to the outside object. I would imagine that returning the final form `global` is still necessary so the caller can see the enter new value of `global` for setting later

Comment: If I have a few functions that I want to mutate a global variable that is passed as a function argument, some can do this by passing just the symbol of the global (as in the case of pushing something onto part of a list), but other functions will require that the symbol be quoted when it is passed so I can access the `symbol-value` and mutate the outside variable, required for using `setq` in a function. This question is basically about creating a consistent interface for a user of these functions without confusing them that sometimes you pass the symbol, othertimes you pass the quoted symbol?